# How to solve this Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cookies')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Hey I am getting an Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cookies')
I have Created a middleware requiressigin that will create cookies when user Signin and also same function will call on Stripe callback Page to get user Stripe Account Status
But i am getting an error i stuck to this from past 3 days Please Check

here is the code

```
export const requireSignin = expressjwt({
    getToken:(res,req)=>req.cookies.token,
    secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ["HS256"],
});
```

Here is my Code in Server.js

```
app.use(cookieParser());
```

And You can check How i am Calling it in my Routes

```
router.post ("/get-account-status",requireSignin,getAccountStatus);
```

Here is the code in my controller

```
export const getAccountStatus = async (req, res) => {
    
    try{
        const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();
        const account= await stripe.accounts.retrieve(user.stripe_accound_id);
        if(!account.charges_enabled)
        {
           return res.status(400).send("Charges Not Enabled");
        }
        else{
           const statusUpdated= await User.findByIdAndUpdate(user._id,{
            stripe_seller:account,
            $addToSet:{role:'Instructor'},
           },
              {new:true}).select("-password").exec();
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch the order of the parameters of your `getToken` function so it is `(req, res)` instead

Comment: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') Now I am getting That error After Changing Order

Comment: and the line in my controller function is 
const user = await User.findById(req.user._id).exec();

Comment: Does your controller have the right parameter order? (req, res)

Comment: Yes IT is in the same order